# Configuring master node in spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

Apologies in advance as I am new to spark. I have created a spark cluster in standalone mode with 4 workers, and after successfully being able to configure worker properties, I wanted to know how to configure the master properties.

I am writing an application and connecting it to the cluster using SparkSession.builder (I do not want to submit it using spark-submit.)

I know that that the workers can be configured in the `conf/spark-env.sh` file and has parameters which can be set such as 'SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY' and 'SPARK_WORKER_CORES'

My question is: How do I configure the properties for the master? Because there is no 'SPARK_MASTER_CORES' or 'SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY' in this file.

I thought about setting this in the `spark-defaults.conf` file, however it seems that this is only used for spark-submit.

I thought about setting it in the application using `SparkConf().set("spark.driver.cores", "XX")` however this only specifies the number of cores for this application to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want to use spark-submit how do you intend to submit jobs to the cluster ?

Comment: My script is in a jupyter notebook which I connected to the spark cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways of setting the configurations of Spark Master node (Driver) and spark worker nodes. I will show examples of setting the memory of the master node. Other settings can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

1- Programatically through SpackConf class.

Example:

```
new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.memory","8g")
```

2- Using Spark-Submit: make sure not to set the same configuraiton in your code (Programatically like 1) and while doing spark submit. if you already configured settings programatically, every job configuration mentioned in spark-submit  that overlap with (1) will be ignored.

example :

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 8g
```

3- through the Spark-defaults.conf: 
In case none of the above is set this settings will be the defaults.

example :

```
spark.driver.memory     8g
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For method 3, does that mean that when I launch spark using `sbin/start-master.sh`, the master node will have 8g memory? or is the 'spark-defaults.conf' file only read when spark-submit is executed?